# trigger change event after picking from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, timepicker

I have a JQuery timepicker defined as

```
<div class="form-group">  
    <label class="col-xs-4 col-md-3 control-label" align="right">
        <div class="pull-right">{{ jc_settings_form.meeting_time.label() }}</div>
    </label>
    <div class='col-xs-8 col-md-9 dateContainer' style="max-width:200px">
        <div class='input-group input-append date'>
            <input type="select" class="form-control timepicker" name="meeting_time" id="meeting_time"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is one option within a form and I would like to run automatic validation of the form whenever the user changes a field so I have some javascript like

```
$('.manage_jc_settings_form')
    .formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        excluded: ':disabled',
        ignore: [],
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            name: { 
                meeting_time: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Please provide a meeting time'
                        }
                    }
                },...
```

for any reason if I pick a time from the timepicker dropdown it does not trigger the change even and therefore does not validate the form? If I click into the text field and change the time manually it does trigger the change even?
Here is my timepicker initialisation

```
(function($) {
    $(function () {
        $('#meeting_time').timepicker({
            defaultTime: '{{ jc_settings_form.meeting_time.default }}',
            dropdown: true,
            scrollbar: true,
            startTime: '9:00 am',
            timeFormat: 'h:mm a', // equivalent to 'h:mm a'
            interval: 5 //Number of minutes the up/down arrow's will move the minutes value in the time picker
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

any idea how to force it to trigger the change event? I thought maybe I have to change the type="text" attribute of the input field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a function on the change event for jQuery Timepicker like this:

```
(function($) {
    $(function () {
        $('#meeting_time').timepicker({
            defaultTime: '{{ jc_settings_form.meeting_time.default }}',
            dropdown: true,
            scrollbar: true,
            startTime: '9:00 am',
            timeFormat: 'h:mm a', // equivalent to 'h:mm a'
            interval: 5,
            change: function(time) {
                alert('things changed');        
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

[It's listed on the docs here.](http://timepicker.co/options/)

Comment: thanks, this seems to work... do you know how to prevent that the change event is triggered during page load?

Comment: Try putting all of your jQuery in a [document ready block](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear from your post what you are trying to do. If you are looking to validate the form every time a different is option is selected from the dropdown, you might want to try using `onchange` as follows:

`<input type="select" class="form-control timepicker" name="meeting_time" id="meeting_time" onchange="yourValidationFunction()" />`

I'd also consider moving away from jQuery whenever possible, as you will probably eventually find its syntactic sugar causes more problems than it solves (not to mention it considerably lengthens page load times).

Comment: do you have a suggestion for an alternative timepicker? I looked around, but wasn't sure which one to pick...

Comment: I personally would just write one manually. That may or may not be an option for you. Are you using a front-end framework like React or Angular?

Comment: I am using flask... and I am not good enough in javascript to write this myself

Comment: Flask is a backend framework, so you're probably just using vanilla JavaScript (no framework) for the frontend.

Comment: yes that's correct... I have to say I am trying to get rid of jquery but my project is now so interwoven with it that it is quite difficult and time-consuming...